# Docker deployment options

Tags: deployment, docker, release-management

I'm wondering which options are there for docker container deployment in production. Given I have separate APP and DB server containers and data-only containers holding deployables and other holding database files.

I just have one server for now, which I would like to "docker enable", but what is the best way to deploy there(remotely will be the best option)

I just want to hit a button and some tool will take care of stopping, starting, exchanging all needed docker containers.

There is myriad of tools(Fleet, Flocker, Docker Compose etc.), I'm overwhelmed by the choices.

Only thing I'm clear is, I don't want to build images with codes from git repo. I would like to have docker images as wrappers for my releases. Have I grasped the docker ideas from wrong end?

Comment: I think this is too open-ended for SO, but take a look at http://rancher.com/.

Comment: I think the question is not to broad, but the selection of tools available is. Anyway your five cents taken in account.

Answer (score 1):

My team recently built a Docker continuous deployment system and I thought I'd share it here since you seem to have the same questions we had. It pretty much does what you asked:
"hit a button and some tool will take care of stopping, starting, exchanging all needed docker containers"

We had the challenge that our Docker deployment scripts were getting too complex. Our containers depend on each other in various ways to make the full system so when we deployed, we'd often have dependency issues crop up.

We built a system called "Skopos" to resolve these issues. Skopos detects the current state of your running system and detects any changes being made and then automatically plans out and deploys the update into production. It creates deployment plans dynamically for each deployment based on a comparison of current state and desired state.

It can help you continuously deploy your application or service to production using tags in your repository to automatically roll out the right version to the right platform while removing the need for manual procedures or scripts.

It's free, check it out: http://datagridsys.com/getstarted/

You can import your system in 3 ways: 
1. if you have a Docker Compose, we can suck that in and start working iwth it. 
2. If your app is running, we can scan it and then start working with it. 
3. If you have neither, you can create a quick descriptor file in YAML and then we can understand your current state.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I think it might be more helpful if you could give a brief explaination on how skopos works, and/or how one would setup/configure it to solve the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think most people start their container journey using tools from [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/toolbox). Those tools provide a good start and work as promised, but you'll end up wanting more. With these tools, you are missing for example integrated overlay networking, DNS, load balancing, aggregated logging, VPN access and private image repository which are crucial for most container workloads.

To solve these problems we started to develop [Kontena](http://www.kontena.io) - Docker Container Orchestration Platform. While Kontena works great for all types of businesses and may be used to run containerized workloads at any scale, it's best suited for start-ups and small to medium sized business who require worry-free and simple to use platform to run containerized workloads.

Kontena is an open source project and you can view it on [GitHub](https://github.com/kontena/kontena).

Comment: Interesting, anyway is it close to Flocker somehow? But anyway this is somehow how I would like it to do it. Some remote manager, sending in some application description. Just now my problem is even broader as there in another tool on the block.

Comment: Flocker is focused more on managing data volumes while Kontena is focused more on container orchestration and application management.

Comment: If I will be deploying mainly new data-only containers (their volumes) with app. deployables, Flocker can be better choice for me?

Comment: Kontena includes stateful services. When you define a service as stateful, Kontena creates data-only container automatically for it. Here is simple example with stateful database: http://blog.kontena.io/automate-deployments-with-kontena-deploy/. 

If you need to scale your application and create High-Availability applications, it's also very easy: http://blog.kontena.io/how-to-build-high-availability-wordpress-site-with-docker/